# Filtering elements jquery

Tags: jquery, css, arrays

I'm trying to make elements filtring in jquery but it behave crazy. Anyone can help to fix it?

```js
$('ul li a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let selected = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $('.container div:visible').addClass('hide');
  $('.container div:hidden').fadeIn(0);
  $('.container div').on("transitionend", function() {
    console.log($('.container div').length);
    $('.container div:not(.' + selected + ')').fadeOut();
    $('.container div.' + selected).fadeIn(100, function() {
      $(this).removeClass('hide');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

ul li a:hover,
ul li a.active {
  color: gold;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.container div {
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.container div.red {
  background: red;
}

.container div.green {
  background: green;
}

.container div.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.container div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.hide {
  transform: scale(0);
}

body {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter="red">red</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter="green">green</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter="blue">blue</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

Hello, I'm trying to make elements filtring in jquery but it behave crazy. Anyone can help to fix it?

Hello, I'm trying to make elements filtring in jquery but it behave crazy. Anyone can help to fix it?

Hello, I'm trying to make elements filtring in jquery but it behave crazy. Anyone can help to fix it?

Comment: Try putting your `transitionend` event handler *outside* the click handler

Comment: I updated your code to a snippet and changed the console.log to something smaller `console.log($('.container div').length);` - when you click (even just once), you'll see that this appears multiple times - it runs for each of the blocks, but your code expects it to only run once.

Comment: "it behave crazy" is not very helpful. You need to be clearer about what exactly the problem is and what you what it to do. We can't help if we don't know what we are supposed to help with.

Comment: @freedomn-m I know it runs multiple times but I don't know why.

Comment: As mentioned in comment above - you have the event assigned to every div inside the container.

Comment: yes, because there're 18 divs to animate and I need function to run after animations

Comment: Maybe if you told us what you want to happen and what "it behave crazy" means, we might be able to help you fix the problem, As I said, if we can't help is we don't know what we're trying to fix...